# How to access KDE's camera:/ from terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, kde, camera, dolphin-file-manager

KDE's device notifier detects my GoPro Hero camera correctly and allows me to access its contents in dolphin through the URI `camera:/`.

Is there a way to access the camera also from the command line? I tried already

- to mount it by clicking on device notifiers "mount" button right to the device, 

   – but nothing happens (also no error message in `journalctl -f`);
- to drop a command line from Dophin's tools menu, 

  – but it is dropped in my home directory;
- to find it in `~/.gvfs`, 

  – but I do not have this directory.

Any ideas how to access KDE's `camera:/` from the command line?